# Excel using table from current workbook for Power Query parameters - more efficient way?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a query setup that uses tables in the same Excel workbook as a source for number of parameters. This is to make it accessible for regular users and easy to change.
Each of the parameter tables is setup as a query:

```
let
   Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
   TableName = Source{[Name="TableName"]}[Content],
   #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(...)
in
   #"Changed Type"
```

Example table:
[image]

After which each of the values are added as separate queries, **which are then used in a 'final' query to filter the output or add columns.**

Because there are number of parameters, the query list looks like this:
[image]

**My question**
Is there a way to dynamically use values from those tables in Power Query without separating them into individual queries for each parameter?

Using the first table as an example, something like `Table1[[Over Limit],[Min]]` (I know this is not a valid syntax)

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: You are probably looking for [this](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2018/05/30/creating-dynamic-parameters-in-power-query/) or [this](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/)..

Comment: I believe that's it @Storax, thank you.